# Added a space between an image and a div using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <img id="image" class="col-md-2" src="img.png">
    </div>
    <div id="otherPart" class="col-md-4">           
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Twitter bootstrap to space my html objects and I want to make it so that my id="image" is dynamic and able to adjust its size depending on the size of the image.  At the same time I still want to have the spacing between my image and and "otherPart".  I tried deleting col-md-2 from image and adding margins in the css but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="yourAdditionalMarginClass">
            <img id="image" src="img.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">   
        <div id="otherPart"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image is responsive now, the basic padding of the col's is applied and if you need even more padding/margin, wrap another div around the image, give it a class and apply your styles to that class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-2">
        <img id="image" src="img.png">
    </div>
    <div id="otherPart" class="col-md-4">           
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `col-md-2` from the image and add it to the outer most div like:

```
<div class="row col-md-2">
    ...
</div>
```