# Missing space between images in Bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, space

I'm a beginner and use Bootstrap 4.
I've done this page: https://www.bitballoon.com/sites/stoker-austin-77536

I would simply like to have some white space between images.

I have tried countless tricks (none work) ie some of them:

- [Trying to use spacing of Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#spacing)
- [Added a space between an image and a div using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769481/added-a-space-between-an-image-and-a-div-using-bootstrap)

I also tried adding Padding on .img .img-fluid (I have now removed it)

my HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="add-padding" class="p-b-2">
            <img src="../img/featured_image_grey1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="add-padding">
    <img src="../img/featured_image_grey1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
    <img src="../img/featured_image_grey1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div> 
</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
.p-b-2 {
  padding-bottom: ($spacer-x * 2) !IMPORTANT;
  padding-bottom: ($spacer-y * 2) !IMPORTANT;
}
.add-padding {
 padding-bottom: 20px !IMPORTANT; 
 margin-bottom: 20px !IMPORTANT;
}
.row .col-md-9 .add-padding{
 padding-bottom: 20px !IMPORTANT;
}
img *{
 padding-bottom:20px !IMPORTANT;
}
```

Comment: The external link needs login. The HTML markup has issues like the class attribute should only be used once in a tag and the semicolons in the img tags. Create a minimal example like this http://codeply.com/go/o3WdEMPo5l

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much @Skelly: I've corrected the rookie errors (you've pointed to) and it now works :)

So the HTML corrections are:

- "class attribute should only be used once in a tag
- and remove semicolons in the img tags"

I created my Codeply:
http://www.codeply.com/go/ZZaV7zlnVO

My only CSS is now:

```
.col-md-9 {
padding-bottom: 40px !IMPORTANT;}
```

The problem came from the HTML errors mentioned above. I had unnecessary CSS (because I had tried so many CSS tricks, not knowing that HTML was the source of the issue). I have now simplified the CSS (see above).

Note: I have only used Bitballoon a week and did not know it was password protected - sorry.